# how to change a bluetooth device properties

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

How do you change a bluetooth device properties? I have a bluetooth HDMX speaker and it's working - connecting to win7 - but under win7 bluetooth devices it is showing up as a headset instead of a speaker? How do I change this without having to remove and restore the device? Thanks!

Comment: Better yet - how to change a bluetooth device catagory from a headset to a speaker?

Answer (score 1):

This particular property is governed by the device itself.  Generally Bluetooth "Speakers" act as more that just speakers.   They usually also have a built in microphone so you can use them to do hands free telephone calls.

I have a set of TSUNAMI speakers by blackweb that showed up like this.  One day I was messing around in the sound properties and noticed that it had a "recording" property that was disabled.   I enabled it and was hugely surprised to here my speakers replaying every sound I made in the room.

Theoretically I could have used this system to place and execute phone calls and that built in mic would have done the job of getting my voice to the other end of the line.

So if your "speakers" are showing up as a headset, there is a good chance they have a built in mic you can use for recording or using voice commands with your computer.

Comment: It's possible that even if they don't have a microphone inside, they may be using a chip that includes that capability in order to keep costs down by ordering lots of a single chip type instead of fewer of multiple chip types.